# Why is Openoffice Calc automatically rounding the sum of two sums?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I have two columns which have been summed. When I sum the two cells with those results, openoffice rounds the sum every time. If I only enter two numbers and then sum them, it operates normally. Anyone have this problem or any suggestions? Everything is formatted as number with two decimal places and I never extend the numbers longer than two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding is not happening in the arithmetic, it is happening in the presentation of the result.  Change the format of the cell having the formula to show more precision in the presented result.  It may be that the format of the cell where you made the sum did not get set to numeric with two decimal places.